# Параметр лямбды

Tags: c#, лямбда-выражение

В одной из книг по EntityFramework есть описание кода:

1. We created an object of the DbContext class:

   ```
   ToDoDBEntities db = new ToDoDBEntities()
   ```
2. Retrieved an item by passing the key values, that is, using the Find function:

   ```
   ToDo todo1 = db.ToDos.Find(id);
   ```
3. Retrieved an item by passing a non-key value using the FirstOrDefault
   function:

   ```
   ToDo todo2 = db.ToDos.SingleOrDefault(item => item.TodoItem == "Test item");
   ```
4. Retrieved an item by passing a non-key value using the SingleOrDefault
   function:

   ```
   ToDo todo2 = db.ToDos.SingleOrDefault(item => item.TodoItem == "Test item");
   ```

Вопрос, откуда берется параметр `item` в лямбда? `item => item.TodoItem ==
"Test item");` Ведь мы его нигде не объявляли.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что при переборе списка будет вызываться Ваша лямбда-функция, которой будет передаваться параметр `item` (название может быть любым) - это элемент списка в текущей итерации. А потом в теле лямбда-функции можно, используя этот параметр, обратиться к элементу в текущей итерации перебора списка и выполнить какое-либо действие.

Конкретно в этом случае, мы в `SingleOrDefault` передаём функцию, которая проверяет равен ли элемент заданному условию `item.TodoItem == "Test item"` и данная лямбда функция возвращает результат этого условия как свой результат.

Это выражение можно **представить** себе следующим образом, **но так делать неправильно, так как у Вас выгрузятся все записи на клиент, вариант с лямбда внутри работает по другому!**

Ваша лямбда функция это как метод:

```
public bool Compare(ToDo item)
{
    return item.TodoItem == "Test item";
}
```

А Ваш вызов `SingleOrDefault`, вызов метода в который мы передаём другой метод, для сравнения объектов:

```
ToDo result = db.ToDos.SingleOrDefault(Compare);
```

Comment: Не совсем так. `Queryable.SingleOrDefault` принимает не делегат, а выражение, поэтому при замене на метод ничего работать не будет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, на минуту засомневался в том, что я написал, но решил проверить. Одна из перегрузок SingleOrDefault:

`public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);`

Comment: Эта перегрузка вытащит **все** строки из таблицы на клиент только для того чтобы найти среди них одну. Нельзя так работать с базой данных!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я не уверен в том, что все записи выгружаются на клиент, но доверюсь Вам, поправил ответ :)

Comment: @Umed, ты перепутал методы из класса [Queryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.queryable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx), которые принимают Expression и методы из класса [Enumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), которые принимают делегат.

Comment: @Grundy, да, точно, спасибо, уже осознал свою ошибку))

Answer (score 1):

Вы его объявляли. Посмотрите внимательнее на вот эту запись:

```
item => item.TodoItem == "Test item"
```

В левой части лямбда-выражения **объявляется** параметр `item`. В данном случае его тип определяется компилятором автоматически, но можно его задать и вручную:

```
(ToDo item) => ...
```

Имя для параметра можно выбирать произвольно (точнее, есть одно ограничение: имя параметра не может совпадать с именем локальной переменной).

В правой части лямбда-выражения **используется** параметр, объявленный в левой части.

Comment: А разве в С# можно передавать функцию в качестве параметра?

Comment: @RVG, у тебя в вопросе два примера передачи функции в качестве параметра:)

Comment: @RVG по моему в наши вообще сложно найти язык, где нельзя передавать функции в качестве параметров.

Comment: я думал через делегаты только